# Migrate user settings from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: home-directory, settings, user-profile

I have a fresh install of ububtu 16.04 in a new hd,  on my old hd my 14.10 i'been using till now. 
I'd like to move all my settings to my new home (all .* files&dirs) 
Any catch and gotchas?

Comment: To migrate a system I use aptik to capture all the installed software and deja-dup to back up home.  Some things slip through the cracks but overall it's pretty solid.

Comment: nice suggestion, i was actually concerned to know about slips in the cracks in system settings